# Select2.js mobile & tablet support

Tags: mobile, cross-browser, jquery-select2, tablet, cross-device

[Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2#browser-compatibility) does indicate its support for **desktop browser version** to be: IE8+, Chrome 8+, Firefox 10+, Safari 3+, Opera 10.6+

However, I cannot find anything regarding Mobile & Tablet support.

Is there any official statement I have missed?

Answer (score 7):

Simply quoting from the [same question I asked on the Github project](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2972#issuecomment-71762666)

> Select2 3.5.x should work well in all of the latest mobile devices.
>   It's used in many large websites and we've appeared to have ironed out
>   many of the old issues.
>
> Select2 4.0.0 has not yet been released, but Beta 3 has been tested to
>   work with Android devices without any real issues. We don't have any
>   iOS devices to test on, but more than likely they work well on iOS as
>   well.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [same question](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2972#issuecomment-71762666), for version 4.0.3 ( current stable release )

> Yes, this version is more stable. Tested on Android 6.0.1 and iPhone 6.